# How do I open this light fixture that has 3 screws / hooks?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, screws, light

In Ireland we have this light fixture:
[image]

It has 3 metal pieces screwed and something like a clasp in front of each screw:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't know if I have to remove the screws or have to do something with the thing that looks like a clasp/hook.

Can a single person remove and put this back?

Comment: If it is nice enough to just turn and release, a single person should be able to do it.  Once you start having to use screwdrivers or something, it would be best to have more people just for safety, holding you on the ladder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it.

First pull the golden ring.
[image]

Then you can pull the glass, which is hold with springy metal pieces.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the pictures you have supplied (very good job BTW) it looks like you can lift it and rotate it until the tabs have disengaged.

Comment: I tried lifting the glass and rotating and it didn't rotate.

Comment: Did you lift the frame or the glass?

Comment: I tried pushing the glass up and rotate at the same time.

Comment: Try lifting the frame around the glass (the metal ring) because I think that is what is holding the glass up. If that doesn't work, try loosening the screws 1/2 turn to relieve some friction and possibly rotate the ring.